# call webmethod with parameter from javascript using Json.Encode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `WebMethod`:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] getDropDown(int idSpacies)
{
    var raceList = from r in db1.breed where r.spaciesID == idSpacies select r;
    string[] temp = new string[raceList.Count()];
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (var item in raceList )
    {
        temp[counter] = item.name;
        counter++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And JavaScript function:

```
function changeSpacies()
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("selectpicker").value;

    var availableTags = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(AlewetWeb.Areas.ClinicService.Controllers.BreedsController.getDropDown(temp)));

      $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
}
```

When I use `temp` variable as parameter in a `WebMethod`'s `getDropDown` call  I receive error

> temp doesn't exist in the current context

How I can pass a JavaScript variable to `WebMethod`.

Comment: Shouldn't you send this `temp` variable through ajax or something? `$.ajax({ type: "POST", data: temp, url: "your\web\URL" });`

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` is razor code - it is parsed on the server before its sent to the browser. `temp` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point. You need to make an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for help, I used ajax and it's working.